# Drop Table and related views constraints etc

Tags: oracle

I'm writing scripts for an Oracle database, looking for a ome thing similar to  MySQL's IF EXISTS construct.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_name`;
```

Is there any easy approach to drop the table and will that script drop all sequence, views, dblinks, constraints etc. Does the drop delete all constraints and also the version specified in answer is 23 and the version which i am having is 18.4
drop   table IF EXIST tbl1;
create table IF NOT EXIST tbl1 (num number, txt varchar2(10)); so this givves error.